# zmap Install Configuration Error

Tags: makefile, installation, centos

I'm having an issue installing zmap on CentOS 6.5 64 bit

I've followed all the directions here: https://zmap.io/download.html

and get the following error;

```
[root@cs307 zmap-1.1.0]# make install
[100%] Built target zmap
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
--
CMake Error at zmap_conf_install.cmake:4 (file):
  file called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:36 (INCLUDE)


make: *** [install] Error 1
[root@cs307 zmap-1.1.0]#
```

The contents of zmap_conf_install.cmake is:

```
foreach(conf_file blacklist.conf;zmap.conf)
        message(STATUS "")
        if(NOT EXISTS "/etc/zmap/")
                file(INSTALL "conf/" DESTINATION "/etc/zmap")
        endif()
endforeach()
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I created the /etc/zmap directory and it worked for me! :)

Comment: This isn't solving the problem and it's not a comprehensive answer.